# Android horizontal line of table row

Tags: java, android, textview

Following creates me dynamic textviews + table rows. Currently it does not look really nice, I want to add a horizontal line after each textview / table row, how do I accomplish that. So far my code looks like this:

```
      jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

      TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
      setContentView(tableRow);
      tableRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

      for(int i= 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String id         = jsonobject.getString("id");
          String content    = jsonobject.getString("content");

          TextView textView = new TextView(context);
          textView.setText(content);
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
              textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
              } else {
                  textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.boldText);
              }
             textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.highlightedTextViewColor);
                    tableRow.addView(textView);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add divider to TableLayout in xml.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:listDivider">
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a separate background file for each row in drawable folder.

2) Set that drawable to each row by using:

```
 row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);
```

row_border file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#88676767"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Ok I created the row_border.xml file inside the drawable folder and called it like this: `tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);
` but somehow I do not see anything now a bug?